# Nested contracts gas fee implication

Tags: gas-price

Let’s say I have a contract calling another contract calling another contract.

Does this also impact the fee for executing the first contract?

Comment: of course, each `CALL` to another contract is about 9,000 GAS, this sums up into total value of gasLimit

Comment: Is it then cheaper to have all calculations done within one contract?